# Shutdown problem in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Sometimes my Ubuntu 16.04 is not shutting down when I am trying to shutdown from the task menu. I am forcing shutdown by pressing the power button. I want to know the reason and solution for this.

Comment: *is not shutting down* means nothing at all happens? Try with `shutdown now`

Comment: run this in the terminal (start it by pressing: (`ctrl+alt+T`) `sudo shutdown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason can be anything, but try running this command to shutdown:

```
sudo systemctl poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shutdown by terminal by this command:
`sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: mayank@mayank-Aspire-5738:~$ sudo shutdown -h now
[sudo] password for mayank: 
Failed to start poweroff.target: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and 'systemctl status poweroff.target' for details.